# Unable to write to file and read from file in base folder of NodeJS/NestJS Microservices Application

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, nestjs

I am trying to write content/response to a file(placed in base folder) from microservice's folder.

Hierarchy of file:
base -> global.config.json

I am trying to write content to global.config.json file from update-config.ts file (location: base -> src -> config -> update-config.ts). *update-config.ts* gets executed via script that I defined in *package.json* of microservice.

Weird thing about this is it is not giving me any exception or error. Next line, successfully running.

```
try {
        await fsPromises.writeFile(filePath, jsonString);
        console.log('Successfully wrote global.config file ');
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
```

Value of *filePath* is coming correct, I checked by printing it using console.log(filePath).

Is there any dependency that needs to be defined for reading from file and writing to file in base folder in NodeJS/NestJS application?

One possible way of reading updated *global.config.json* file - (Not an ideal solution)

- Whenever I delete *dist* folder before starting any microservice then, it is able to make copy of updated *global.config.json* in *dist* folder of that microservice. Through this, I'm able to get updated values.
  But, for this I need to delete *dist* folder explicitly everytime before starting any microservice.

Kindly, help with this.